# Stripe future payment getting error No such SetUpIntent for version 16.1.1

Tags: android, stripe-payments

When stripe.confirmSetupIntent is called, it's getting failed with error: No Such SetUpIntent. Verified publishable and secret key pair from frontend and backend but still face the same issue.
PaymentMethodCreateParams.Card card = m_stripeCard.getPaymentMethodCard();

```
if (card != null) {
PaymentMethod.BillingDetails billingDetails =
new PaymentMethod.BillingDetails.Builder()
.setEmail(AccountUtils.currentUser.getEmail())
.build();

PaymentMethodCreateParams paymentMethodParams = PaymentMethodCreateParams
.create(card, billingDetails);
ConfirmSetupIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmSetupIntentParams
.create(paymentMethodParams, clientSecret);
stripe.confirmSetupIntent(thisActivity, confirmParams);
}
```

This is how i'm creating setupIntent confirm parameters.

Not getting what's causing issue here.

Comment: Make sure your clientSecret is set in your Android Application? what was the clientSecret? Can you log it in the frontend?

Comment: @wsw clientSecret is being retrieved from the backend and also verified that using same clientSecret on both ends

Comment: are you using Stripe Connect? I saw a lot of case besides the key mismatching (either using different account or using live/test key wrong), most of the time is because they are creating setupIntent in the connected account but confirm on the platform account

Comment: @wsw yes, we are using connect account but how'd we come to know that through which account are we confirming the setupIntent as we are only passing the clientSecret(received from backend) to setupIntent confirm parameters

Comment: @Nasser, this will require your application to match the account. 
E.g. one way to do this is to make sure your frontend app is tied to an account and could only request client secret from this account. For security reason, you might not want one of your customer (connected account) to have access to another account's setupintent client secret even though it is ok 
Or another way, your server should pass client secret together with the accountId this client secret is for, and your frontend would create pm on that account to set it up

Comment: @NaseerAttari Hi Naseer, I am having the same issue as you. Did you end up finding the solution?

Comment: @devOP1 yes, for me there was issue with keys as server was using different key so I updated the key in .env file.